# Objective-C ISA pointer on disk vs when object being instantiated

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-2.0

The Objective-C runtime ISA pointer is [defined](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-818.2/runtime/objc-private.h.auto.html) as such:

```c
union isa_t {
    isa_t() { }
    isa_t(uintptr_t value) : bits(value) { }

    uintptr_t bits;

private:
    // Accessing the class requires custom ptrauth operations, so
    // force clients to go through setClass/getClass by making this
    // private.
    Class cls;

public:
#if defined(ISA_BITFIELD)
    struct {
        ISA_BITFIELD;  // defined in isa.h
    };

    bool isDeallocating() {
        return extra_rc == 0 && has_sidetable_rc == 0;
    }
    void setDeallocating() {
        extra_rc = 0;
        has_sidetable_rc = 0;
    }
#endif

    void setClass(Class cls, objc_object *obj);
    Class getClass(bool authenticated);
    Class getDecodedClass(bool authenticated);
};
```

The bits fields can be read by the definitions [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-818.2/runtime/isa.h.auto.html).

When I read a macho from disk and go to the `_objc_classlist` section and follow a `objc_class` which is [defined](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-818.2/runtime/objc-runtime-new.h.auto.html) as such:

```c
struct objc_class : objc_object {
  objc_class(const objc_class&) = delete;
  objc_class(objc_class&&) = delete;
  void operator=(const objc_class&) = delete;
  void operator=(objc_class&&) = delete;
    // Class ISA;
    Class superclass;
    cache_t cache;             // formerly cache pointer and vtable
    class_data_bits_t bits;    // class_rw_t * plus custom rr/alloc flags
    ...
```

and `objc_object` is [defined](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-818.2/runtime/objc-private.h.auto.html) as such:

```c
struct objc_object {
private:
    isa_t isa;

public:
    ...
```

meaning that I should be able to interpret the first 8 bytes of `objc_class` as the `bits` field of an `isa`, but when I do this and try to interpret the bits I get random and false information,
on the other hand if I interpret the first 8 bytes as a pointer, it leads me to another `objc_class` instance on disk, which is usually the metaclass of the class. I wonder then why is the definition of the `isa` union from the Objective-C runtime and its `bits` field. Is this only right to interpret this as `isa` union with `bits` when we instantiate an object of a some kind and when reading from disk it's just a pointer to a meta class definition?

**EDIT:**
The way I read the `objc_class` struct from file is with python:

```py
ISA_MASK = 0x0000000ffffffff8

@dataclass
class Isa():
    bits: ctypes.c_size_t
    _cls: ctypes.c_size_t

    def __init__(self, fp, addr):
        fp.seek(addr)
        self.bits = struct.unpack("<Q", fp.read(8))[0]
        self._cls = self.bits

    def nonpointer(self):
        return self.bits & 1
    
    def has_assoc(self):
        return (self.bits >> 1) & 1
    
    def has_cxx_dtor(self):
        return (self.bits >> 2) & 1
    
    def shiftcls(self):
        return (self.bits >> 3) & 0x7ffffffff
    
    def magic(self):
        return (self.bits >> 36) & 0x3f
    
    def weakly_referenced(self):
        return (self.bits >> 42) & 1
    
    def unused(self):
        return (self.bits >> 43) & 1

    def has_sidetable_rc(self):
        return (self.bits >> 44) & 1

    def extra_rc(self):
        return (self.bits >> 45) & 0x7ffff

    def get_class(self):
        clsbits = self.bits
        clsbits &= ISA_MASK
        return clsbits


@dataclass
class ObjcObject:
    isa: Isa
    _addr: ctypes.c_size_t

    def __init__(self, fp, addr, isa_class, external_block_addr):
        self.isa = None
        self._addr = addr

        fp.seek(addr)

        isa_addr = struct.unpack("<Q", fp.read(8))[0]
        if isa_addr != 0 and isa_addr < external_block_addr:
            self.isa = Isa(fp, isa_addr, external_block_addr)
@dataclass
class ObjcClass(ObjcObject):
    super_class: ObjcClass
    cache: Cache
    class_ro: ClassRo

    def __init__(self, fp, addr, external_block_addr):
        super().__init__(fp, addr, ObjcClass, external_block_addr)
        ...
        ...
```

I have for example a class lets call it `A` and after processing the chained fixups on address `0x0025eed0` I have it it's symbol `_OBJC_CLASS_$_A` and the `objc_class` defined in that addres.

The first 8 bytes of the structure is the ISA as we've established by looking at the sources of the runtime. Following it as a **pointer** and not treating it as the `isa_t` union I get to another `objc_class` struct for the symbol `_OBJC_METACLASS_$_A` which is the metaclass of this class.

Now if instead of treating the first 8 bytes of the `objc_class` struct as a pointer to the metaclass, I try to interpret them as the bits of the `isa_t` union like I have in the code I provided, and for example using the `has_cxx_dtor` method I get `False` which is incorrect because I can clearly find this method on the `method_list_t` structure of the `class_ro` so it doesn't match up with what I parse and hence the `isa_t` union seem unrelated to the actual data of the class on disk.

Note that the method for extracting the data from the bits of `isa_t` is by looking at the source of [`isa.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-818.2/runtime/isa.h.auto.html) and assuming I read an ARM64 macho without ptr auth and not from simulator.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to read and interpret these bits? There might be something specific in the access that's leading to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @ItaiFerber it's not just something I can share on stackoverflow, it's too big. But its basically walking the load commands of a macho, fixing chained fixups finding the `__objc_classlist` section and getting to the `objc_class` structures defined in the file and reading them according to the definition in the runtime. The only quirk I found is that the ISA field is basically just another pointer to `objc_class` usually a metaclass of the current class, and all this bit field mean nothing atleast when I read the `objc_class` from disk

Comment: I don't necessarily mean for you to share the whole code, just a snippet showing off exactly how you're reading and interpreting the isa; without some minimal reproducible code, it'll be hard to help much more... And when you say that the "bit field mean[s] nothing", what are the bits that you expect vs. the bits you're getting? Given that the field is a union, the bits should represent exactly the integer value of the pointer...

Comment: @ItaiFerber I've provided additional information on how I parse the structs and what I see compared to what I expect to see and what I actually see that contradicts other data I extract like the method_list of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging a bit through the runtime, it appears that non-pointer isas are a runtime-only concept, and that all on-disk isas will always be regular pointers.

The loading process of Obj-C classes in an object file:

1. `dyld` calls `_objc_map_images` (`objc-internal.h`/`objc-runtime-new.mm`), passing in the object headers to read and load classes from
2. `_objc_map_images` does a bit of setup before calling `map_images` (`objc-private.h`/`objc-runtime-new.mm`)
3. `map_images` takes the runtime lock, then calls `map_images_nolock` (`objc-private.h`/`objc-os.mm`)
4. `map_images_nolock` iterates over the mach headers, searching for Obj-C info and performing some validation. It passes all of the headers which contain Obj-C classes to `_read_images` (`objc-private.h`/`objc-runtime-new.mm`)
5. `_read_images` is where we actually get to the interesting parts. It first sets up support for non-pointer isas as relevant for the runtime target, and sets up some tables for storing class information. After reading and fixing up selectors, it starts reading class info (`OBJC_RUNTIME_DISCOVER_CLASSES_START()`)

   - For each header, it iterates over the raw `classlist` stored in the header, receiving direct pointers to each of the classes in the image
   - For each class read this way, it calls `readClass` (`objc-runtime-new.mm`), which resolves mangled class names, Swift classes, and more — but at the end of the day, the read `classref_t` (raw pointer to dyld class) is either cast to `Class` (the class object), or replaced by an allocated `Class` instance

So, where *do* non-pointer isas come into play? Only when setting objects' class at runtime:

1. When you create an object via either `objc_constructInstance` or `class_createInstance` (`runtime.h`), or set an object's class via `object_setClass`, the object has either `objc_object::initInstanceIsa` or `objc_object::initIsa` (`objc-object.h`) called on it (and `initInstanceIsa` just calls through to `initIsa` anyway)
2. `objc_object::initIsa` has two implementations (one for `SUPPORT_NONPOINTER_ISA` and the other for non-supported), but both call down to `isa_t::setClass` (`objc-private.h`/`objc-object.h`)
3. `isa_t::setClass` also has two implementations — when `SUPPORT_NONPOINTER_ISA` is true, the implementation sets the appropriate bits in the isa value itself, setting `shiftcls` as necessary; when `SUPPORT_NONPOINTER_ISA` is false, it just sets the class directly

(Or in reverse, if you prefer: `isa_t::setClass` is *only* called from `objc_object::initIsa`/`objc_object::changeIsa`, which themselves are *only* called from `objc_constructInstance`/`class_createInstance`/`object_setClass`.)

So, when you read these object files on disk, you will only ever encounter pointer isas for objects and classes; the bits that are actually set inside of isas is done at runtime exclusively. If there are details you're hoping to read from those bits, you'll need to construct that info yourself from the surrounding mach-o data.

Comment: So it was as I thought that it's runtime information only, thanks Itai for the wonderful explanation!

Comment: @Jorayen Happy to have helped! I'd meant to comment and say thanks for adding detail to your question, because it prompted me to go digging in the runtime to see what was going on. I feel like I've learned some valuable stuff!